# zend controller - page not found

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I am new to Zend framework. I am using the Zend 1.12 framework in Ubuntu 12.04.
I have installed the zf tool and it is working fine. I created the controller using:

```
zf create controller test
```

It created the controller in my controller folder and view in the respective directory.

But the problem is when I am using this url:

```
http://localhost/zftest/public/index/index
```

it worked well and opened the default view of Zend.

But when I try to open the custom controller:

```
http://localhost/zftest/public/test
```

it gives me an error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /zftest/public/test was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

This is the link which helped me configure Zend: [zend configuration](http://www.developmentwall.com/install-zend-framework-ubuntu/)

Comment: Rudra, As your default page working fine, So test page should also work Just try add action in url like   http://localhost/zftest/public/test/add

Comment: hi kuldeep, this is the strange problem which i am facing , i can not open any other controller,exept index controller. It gives me the error 404 not found.

Comment: I think you need to add action to url, Zend may not work only through controller in url. So pattern must be http://localhost/zftest/public/[controller]/[action]. Until you set the routing urls in configuration which will be later topic in learning process

Comment: Oh now I understand problem. You must set AllowOverride in file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default then restart apache. It is necessary to make working for .htaccess See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must first set the AllowOverride directive from None to All in apache virtual host file. In you  case your host is localhost. So file will be /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default. See entry like

```
<Directory /var/www/>
```

You will found AllowOverride directive. Set it like

```
AllowOverride All
```

Then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then refresh Page.